# My data never fill my class with codable protocol

Tags: swift, swift4, codable, decodable

I'm setting up a new class from a string formated like a JSON.
When I try to look for the data after the work of codable protocol inside a news.msg for exemple I found nothing.

```
let jsonNews = """
[
{
"idPlace": "HexaId",
"namePlace": "A random name",
"dateMsg": "Timestamp",
"msg": "Message to display",
"urlPicture": "Url of the pic"
},
{
 "idPlace": "HexaId 2",
 "namePlace": "A random name 2",
 "dateMsg": "Timestamp 2",
 "msg": "Message to display 2",
 "urlPicture": "Url of the pic"
}
]
"""    

func getNews(){
var arrayNews: [News] = [News]()

if let dataFromString = jsonNews.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    let json = try! JSON(data: dataFromString)
    for elem in json{
        debugPrint(elem.1)
        guard let data = try? elem.1.rawData() else {
            debugPrint("An error has occurred")
            return
        }
        guard let news = try? JSONDecoder().decode(News.self, from: data) else{
            debugPrint("An error has occurred")
            return

        }
        debugPrint(news.msg)
        arrayNews.append(news)
    }
}


import Foundation
import UIKit

class News: NSObject, Codable {
    let idPlace: String = ""
    let namePlace: String = ""
    let dateMsg: String = ""
    let msg: String = ""
    let urlPicture: String = ""
}
```

When I try to display  `news.msg` or any other property from News class are empty

Comment: Why does `News` extend `NSObject`? Why is it a class and not a struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your json is just an array of objects, there is no need for foreach loop and you can just specify that result from decoding should be array of `News` by putting type of result to square brackets: `[News].self`

```
guard let news = try? JSONDecoder().decode([News].self, from: Data(jsonNews.utf8)) else {
    debugPrint("An error has occurred")
    return
}

debugPrint(news)
arrayNews = news
```

---

Also, if there is no specific reason why your model should inherit from `NSObject`, you can make your model simpler by making it `struct`. Also you don't need default values, since all values will be assigned by decoder initializer

```
struct News: Decodable {
    let idPlace, namePlace, dateMsg, msg, urlPicture: String
}
```

Comment: So what is data inside JSONDecoder().decode([News].self, from: data)

Comment: @BadrFilali it is `dataFromString`, sorry, my mistake

Comment: The problem was the let variable but I got also a bad usage of codable. That work perfectly.Now

Comment: @BadrFilali variables are declared with `var`, constants with `let`, so if you need, you can just change this keyword inside class/struct properties declartion. Anyway, I'm glad it works! ;)

Comment: UTF8 data from a string will never fail. You can even use the `Data` API which returns a non-optional `let dataFromString = Data(jsonNews.utf8)`